# Copy xarray into larger xarray in python?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray of shape [3,] that looks like this

`data= [2,4,6]`

and I'm trying to copy it into array so that it looks like this:

`data= [[2,4,6],[2,4,6],[2,4,6]]`
(ie the entire array is copied three times).

I've tried a few different methods but keep getting:

`data= [2 2 2,4 4 4,6 6 6]`

Anyone know how I should go about doing this? (Also, sorry if I wrote this not according to the stack overflow rules, this is my first question...)

Comment: I'm not sure that the existing answers give you what you really want.  You have to be more precise when you say "copy it into array".  What do you mean by "array"?  Do you mean a standard Python list, or something else?  Also, do you want to make three new and unique copies of your original array or just reference the existing array three times in the new structure?  The existing answers both create a standard Python list and don't actually copy the data, but rather just reference it three times, so if you change a value in one array, it will change in all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two answers don't actually copy the original array/list.  Rather, they both just reference the array three times inside a new list.  If you change one of the values inside of the the original array or any of the "copies" inside the new list, all of the "copies" of the array will change because they're really all the same structure just referenced in multiple places.

If you want to create a list containing three unique copies of your original array (xarray or list), you can do this:

```
new_list = [data[:] for _ in range(3)]
```

or if you want a new xarray containing your original array:

```
new_array = xarray.DataArray([data[:] for _ in range(3)])
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think the safest approach would be this:

```
import itertools

data = [2,4,6]
res = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 3) for x in [data]))
print(res)

Output: [[2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: This example produces `NameError: name 'lst' is not defined`.  Once that is fixed by replacing `lst` with `data`, what is "safest" about this approach?  It suffers from the same problem that the first two answers suffer from...it doesn't copy the original array, but rather just creates a list of references to the original array.  At least that fact is obvious with the first two answers.  With yours, it's a lot harder to tell what is going on. In the end though, your complex answer produces the exact same result as `res = [data] * 3`.

Comment: So, you downvoted my answer for a typo as compared to similar answers who provide  the same result, i.e. reference instead of copy. Alright

Comment: No, I downvoted your answer because it adds a ton of unnecessary complexity.  That's why I asked you what the purpose of it was...what was more "safest" about it.  If you could update your answer with a vallid explanation for why your method is more safe than others, and if I agreed with you, I'd then remove my downvote.  Otherwise, the added complexity is a definite negative given that it adds nothing of value over the simpler approaches, and is hard to read and understand. (and also requires an extra module, which the others don't).